# Keep focus inside the modal while open

Tags: javascript, typescript, modal-dialog, web-component

I want to keep the focus inside the modal with its respective focusable elements, I'm working with "WEB COMPONENTS, DOW AND SHADOW DOW"

when trying to perform this code snippet, focus still continues to show error and go to elements outside the modal

```
private setFocus(): void {
    const focusableElements = this.querySelectorAll('a[href], button, details, input, select, textarea, [tabindex]:not([tabindex="-1"]), ani-button, ani-textfield');
    const firstFocusableElement = focusableElements[0];
    const lastFocusableElement = focusableElements[focusableElements.length - 1];

    this.addEventListener('keydown', event => {
      const isTabbed = event.key === 'Tab' || event.code === '9';

      if (!isTabbed) {
        return;
      }

      if (event.shiftKey) {
        if (document.activeElement === firstFocusableElement) {
          (lastFocusableElement as HTMLElement).focus();
          event.preventDefault();
        }
      } else {
        if (document.activeElement === lastFocusableElement) {
          (firstFocusableElement as HTMLElement).focus();
          event.preventDefault();
        }
      }
    });

    (firstFocusableElement as HTMLElement).focus();
  }

  open(): void {
    // this.hidden = false;
    this.setAttribute('visible', 'true');
    this.setFocus();
  }
```

Comment: So did you debug to see if it gos into the if/else statements?

Comment: Have you asked Google? https://www.google.com/search?q=shadow+dom+focus And use the [< >] button in the StackOverflow Editor to create a executable SO snippet, you are now posting half your code.

Comment: your code looks actually fine. could it be that you have multiple radio inputs? because in that case the focus goes automatically to the selected one (and you go trough them by arrow keys) which might not be your first/last element in your focusableelements but a sibling radio which is the last/first one.
Or you might have your form controls in the shadow DOM but searching them in the light DOM by using `this.querySelectorAll`
There is also the `inert` attribute (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/inert) which can be helpful, although not supported by FF now.